# how to get the turncontext in startup middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, middleware, chatbot

I am working with bot framework v4. Is there any way to get ITurncontext in startup.cs to set up the transcriptlogger middleware for saving the bot state.

Below given the sample solution i have tried

```
IStorage userDataStore = new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.AzureBlobStorage(Configuration["AzureTableStorageConnectionString"], Configuration["AzureBlobStorageContainerName"]);

var userstate = new UserState(userDataStore);

var myPropertyAccessor = userstate.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));

services.AddSingleton<IStatePropertyAccessor<UserProfile>>(myPropertyAccessor);

var logger = new TranscriptLogger(Configuration);
            services.AddTransient<ITranscriptLogger, TranscriptLogger>();
            services.AddBot<DialogAndWelcomeBot<Dialog>>(options =>
            {
                options.CredentialProvider = new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(Configuration);
                
                options.Middleware.Add(new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(logger));
               
            });
```

Implementation of TranscriptLogger :-

```
public class TranscriptLogger : ITranscriptLogger
    {
        public IConfiguration _configuration;
        public TranscriptLogger(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public async Task LogActivityAsync(IActivity activity)
        {
            var isMessage = activity.AsMessageActivity() != null ? true : false;
            
            if (isMessage && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.AsMessageActivity().Text))
            {

            // saving conversation data
            }
        }
    }
```

I really appreciate any help :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KyleDelaney , please see the below comment

Comment: You just posted an answer, not a comment. Please provide all needed information by editing the question itself and not by posting answers. You may provide some additional information in *comments* if it doesn't include any images or code, but that still shouldn't be posted as an answer. In any case, what is the relevance of the sample code you posted? I don't see any reference to a transcript logger middleware in it.

Comment: @KyleDelaney,  I have edited the post

Comment: Okay it's unclear from your code why you would want ITurnContext in Startup. Rather than asking how to get a turn context in Startup, did you perhaps mean to ask how to get transcript logger middleware working? If so, can you explain how you want to log the activities and why that would require a turn context?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, Thank you for your response, I have sorted it out.

Comment: What was your solution? Would you be willing to post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have added Imiddleware implementation in my custom transcriptLogger there by i can able to access the Iturncontext.

```
     public class TranscriptLogger : IMiddleware
     {
            public IConfiguration _configuration;
            private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<UserProfile> _greetingStateAccessor;
            public TranscriptLogger(IConfiguration configuration, UserState userState)
            {
                _configuration = configuration;
                _greetingStateAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile> 
                 (nameof(UserProfile));
            }
           public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, 
                                      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
           {
                var userStateData = await _greetingStateAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () 
                                  => new UserProfile());
    
    
                turnContext.OnSendActivities(async (newContext, activities, nextSend) =>
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Activity currentActivity in 
                             activities.Where(a => a.Type == ActivityTypes.Message))
                    {
                        
                       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentActivity.AsMessageActivity().Text))
                            // Save conversation data...
                    }
                    return await nextSend();
                });
         
    }
}
```